# Should I include the gitignore file in a Visual Studio solution?

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have added the `LICENSE` and the `README.md` files (initially created in the solution folder by GitHub without Visual Sudio knowing about them) by means of the Add Existing Item (Ctrl+Shift+A) feature and now they appear in the Solution Explorer under `Solution Items` node. Should I, perhaps, do the same to the `.gitignore` file? I have customized the `.gitignore` file manually, it is not a standard auto-generated one.

UPDATE: Okay, in case it's a matter of oppinion, let the question be interpreted like "what are, if any, practical pros and cons of making `.gitignore` files a part of a Visual Studo solution?"

I don't mean just createing a `.gitignore` in the same folder on the disk (this is virtually unquestionable, `.gitignore` files are essential for using Git with Visual Studio solutions as Visual Studio generates tons of stuff that ought to be ignored by source control) but actually making it tracked by Visual Studio itself the way like code files, resource files etc.

Comment: I think this is a matter of opinion. *My opinion* is that files you don't expect to be edited or viewed manually with Visual Studio should not be included in the solution.

Comment: I agree with crashmstr in general. But we have all put an image file or a sound file that was not expected to be viewed or edited by VS into a solution, but we wanted them in source. (though having a content management system for a website of any noticeable size is better than having large files in your source.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My personal opinion is that a .gitignore file should not be included in a VS solution. A solution file is supposed to be for opening, compiling, and perhaps deploying a set of Visual Studio projects that are related to one another.
A .gitignore file is not related to the VS solution, or to any of its projects. It is not necessary to build or deploy, or run a solution.

That being said, I don't think it would hurt you in any way, unless you try to build or deploy a solution without the .gitignore . It is possible some build servers will throw an error if the file is missing, and you really don't want to deploy your .gitignore file I imagine.